# Visual Studio 2008 "randomly" hangs on test run

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

We are using VS 2008 Team System with the automated test suite, and upon running tests the test host "randomly" locks up. I actually have to kill the VSTestHost process and re-run the tests to get something to happen, otherwise all tests sit in a "pending" state.

Has anyone experience similar behavior and know of a fix? We have 3 developers here experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this brocc?

Comment: I also ran in that issue today. If VSTestHost.exe hangs with 100% try this BugFix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417021/vs2008-unit-test-pending-and-the-test-cannot-be-completed/1417154

Comment: It went away with a new desktop

Answer (score 4):

This may be related to an obscure bug that causes unit tests to hang unless the computer name is UPPERCASE. Crazy, I know - but I had this problem and the fix worked for me.

[Bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=403799) on MS Connect
[Workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=403799) on MS Connect
[TFS Blog Article](http://teamfoundation.blogspot.com/2008/12/case-of-never-ending-unit-tests.html) about this issue
[HowTo](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/fd6f2128-e248-4336-b8be-1eb5480e3de8/) edit the registry to change your computer name

The easiest approach is to tweak the registry. You need to edit two keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName
```

Change value ComputerName to be upper case in both keys, and restart. Tests then magically work.

Comment: That's what we call Epic Fail :D

Comment: Hmm they are both in uppercase with me, but the test still hangs :(

Answer (score 2):

When you say lock up, do you mean VS is actually hung, or do the tests not run?

The easiest way to track down what is going on would be to look at a dump of the hung process. If you are on Vista, just right-click on the process and choose to create a memory dump. If you are on Windows XP, and don't have the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) installed, you can get a memory dump using ntsd.exe. You'll need the process ID, which you can get from Task Manager by adding the PID column to the Processes tab display.

Once you have that, run the following commands:

```
ntsd -p <PID>
.dump C:\mydump.dmp
```

You can then either inspect that dump using [WinDBG and SOS](http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/11/13/getting-started-with-windbg-part-i.aspx) or if you can post the dump somewhere I'd be happy to take a look at it.

In any case, you'll want to likely take two dumps about a minute apart. That way if you do things like !runaway you can see which threads are working which will help you track down why it is hanging.

One other question - are you on VS2008 SP1?

Answer (score 2):

I would try running the tests from the command line using [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486(VS.80).aspx).  This might help isolate the problem to Visual Studio, and at least give you some method of running the tests successfully.

Comment: I have this problem in VS2010.  Works from the command line, but not in VS.