# VS2008 Unit test "Pending" and the test cannot be completed

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm using VS2008 (with windows XP).

Every time I try to run a unit test it stays on **"Pending"** and the test cannot be completed.

I tried to reinstall VS, but it didn't help.

Any advice?

Comment: Perhaps your test simply "hangs". did you try to debug the test and see where it stops?

Comment: It stopped on the last "}" braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [KB970449 Hotfix in Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=19617) that solved this issue.